# What can we add as "Usage guidance (excerpt)" for "Discussion" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag

What can we set as Usage guidance or excerpt of the tag:[discussion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)?

I propose this:

> Questions (esp. meta questions) that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective.
>   It leads to free passing of **opinions**, **talks**, **ideas**, **experiences**, **suggestions**, in order to **reach a decision** or simply to **exchange ideas**.

Any proposals or edits?

Answer (score 1):

For the specific proposal:

- There is no [discussion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) on the main site, and it sounds like any question which would get this tag should be closed as subjective.  See: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- On this meta site, I think it'd be okay after changing "Questions (esp. meta questions)..." to "Questions about the main site..." (and getting rid of the bold text).

Since it came up in the review queue, **it seems this is now done**.

I don't see much harm in diving in and editing these things.  Even if it turns out to be an outright mistake, it only takes a moment to fix.

---

In general, the guidelines for tag wiki excerpts can be found here: [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts).  I'll copy/paste part of it below:

> **What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?**
>
> 1. The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
> 2. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
> 3. Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.
> 4. Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.
> 5. Some tags are common knowledge.

And the default tag wiki excerpt says:

> Usage guidance, also known as a tag wiki excerpt, is **a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically**.

I'm hoping we can systematically go through all tag wiki excerpts on the main site, as very few describe how to actually use the tag, instead giving a definition.  E.g.:

- This is good: [woman](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woman): "Questions about or that apply specifically to women."
- This is bad: [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia): "Sharia (Islamic Law) based on the teachings of the Qur'an and Sunnah."

I suspect having the tag wiki excerpts poorly maintained over the years has led to a lot of mistagging.

---

For reference, the StackExchange counterparts [meta.Christianity.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [meta.Judaism.SE](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [meta.Buddhism.SE](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [meta.Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) all write:

> The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.

---

Oh, and welcome to Islam.SE!  *smiles*